# The relevant error-causing widget was Column | flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

showing this error when I use column in StreamBuilder

error:

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#6d45d relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
package:flutter/…/rendering/box.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 2001 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
Column

[image]

```
body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("posts")
              .orderBy('datePublished', descending: true)
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context,
              AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
            
            //connection no problem
            return Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 100.0,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemCount: 5,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                      height: 250,
                      width: 150,
                      color: Colors.pink,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => PostCard(
                    snap: snapshot.data!.docs[index].data(),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            );
          },
        ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListView` need bounded size, when you wrap it with `Expanded` you set its bound, try this:

```
Expanded(
    child: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => PostCard(
        snap: snapshot.data!.docs[index].data(),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```